# FitText trouble with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a small project at the moment and one of the last things I need to do is create a nice responsive heading.

I found [FitText.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js) and the downloaded demo works fine, but, somehow, when I put it into my bootstrap based WP theme, it's not working. I've tried the non-jquery version as well, but without success. Could anybody help me solve the problem? Why is the FitText is not working correctly?

code:

```
<div id="front">
  <div class="site-header">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">

                  <h1 class="tafont" id="logo-text">Think Arch 2015</h1>

                  </div>
             </div>
        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div> <!-- /.site-header -->
</div> <!-- /#front -->
```

css:

```
#logo-text{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            text-align: center;
            font: 95px/1 "Impact";
            display: block;          
}
```

js:

```
jQuery("#logo-text").fitText();
```

I've added that into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd87dpyu/), but there it works, any idea what to do?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? It looks like the fiddle is working correctly.

Comment: I don't know, it looks like whole function is not working in my wp template and I have no clue why, fiddle works fine and application is pretty easy...

Comment: Maybe check and make sure everything is loaded correctly, chrome developer tools is great for this.

Comment: It looks like it is loaded correctly, I've found another way around (using different script), but I really don't understand what was wrong. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, haha. Maybe you have something else jquery/javscript conflicting with fitttext.